# Sparx Enterprise Architect: undo get all latest

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have Sparx EA setup with version control. Prior to checking in updates to my model I did a get all latest. But doing so has completely mangled one of my diagrams. This is particularly odd as:

1. The packages that contained the diagram and all the components in the diagram were checked out by me - so there is no way these should ever be updated the get all latest.
2. In any case I'm the only one who has ever worked on this model.

What appears to have happened is that that I refactored a large diagram into three separate ones, buy cutting and pasting some components from the original into new diagram, leaving the original with a subset of the original components. The get all latest seems to have re-inserted all the original components and connections back into the original diagram and even re-locating some of the components in the original diagram, leaving an utter mess.

Is there any way to undo the actions of what I can only assume is a pretty serious bug?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not undo that unless you have a database backup. If you have not committed your work before, it's your own fault.

FWIW: Get All Latest is meant to be used in single distributed EAP files (or RDBMS remote to a central repos). It will erase all work and replace it with what has been stored in the VC system.

**Edit**: Although the help states

> The Get All Latest command does not update any package that is checked-out (to anybody) in the currently loaded project; otherwise, any changes not yet committed to version control would be discarded

this may affect current diagraming work. The simple reason is that a diagram content can well rely on other packages being altered during a Get All Latest. It also depends on whether one saves diagram changes which are otherwise held in memory and can cause trouble.

Anyhow, there is no undo for Get All Latest for sure. Go into a dark chamber, cry out loud and start doing it once again. Just revert to an older commit first.

Comment: Really! So if I have a package (ie the xml file) checked out then synchronizing (Get All Latest) with the VC will overwrite this -and without warning or making a backup. That's behaviour out of the Ark! In fact that runs counter to the documentation: "The 'Get All Latest' command does not update any Package that is checked-out (to anybody) in the currently loaded project; otherwise, any changes not yet committed to version control would be discarded"

Comment: Hmm. I was not thinking of a package being checked out :-[ I'll give it a try later. However, I urged my customers to stop using this function in particular (and VC in general) due to the many times the repository was ruined by wrong application of Get All Latest. Switching to nightly snapshots and user security solved all those issues.